# (PHP)(HTML)Login Only Going to 1 Page

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

My user page is The only one being accessed for both.
Within my Database and table each are divided by 'type'
0 = user and 1 = admin.

my Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbcon.php';
?> 

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Login Page</tItle>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css">
 </head>
 <body>

  <form class="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
  <div class="form-field">
      <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off"></div>

      <div class="form-field">
      <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password"></div>


      <div class="form-field">  
      <input type="submit" value="login"></div>
     </form>
     </body>
     </html>
     <?php

    if ($_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_METHOD' ] == 'POST')
  {
  $usernane = $_POST['username'];
  $password = sha1($_POST['password' ]);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND 
  password = ? LIMIT 1");
  $stmt->execute(array($usernane, $password));
  $checkuser = $stmt->rowCount();
  $user = $stmt->fetch();
```

I believe This is where I am The Mistake Can Be.

When Ever I log into my User page it gets redirected to the Admin Page.

When I try to adjust the code most of the time only 1 page works.

Any help will be appreciated!

```
     if ($checkuser === 0)
  {
  $_SESSION[ 'user' ] = $user['username'];
  $_SESSION[ 'type'] = $user['type'];
  header('location:Home.php');

  }if ($checkuser === 1)
  {
  $_SESSION[ 'user' ] = $user['username'];
  $_SESSION[ 'type'] = $user['type'];
  header('location:sample2.php');

  }
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: `if ($type = 1)` should be `if ($type == 1)` and rather than `==` you perhaps want to use `===` for strict equality checking

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Also, be warned that `sha1` is not the best algorithm to securely hash your passwords

Comment: Thank you for the response. But both logins are now going into my UserPage.php

Comment: @NicoHaase Ive tried just making it an else but same problem occured. Also tried a switch case for that but same issues again

Comment: you have no `type` field in the form and why would you let the user specify the type anyway? The `type` should be selected from the table upon successful logon. Please add the missing portion of PHP from the login piece

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I will recheck my code! thank you

Comment: If I had the option to be an admin user or regular user simply by changing the type from 0 to 1 I know which I'd choose!

Comment: I have edited it but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you store a correctly hashed password using `password_hash` then the following, untested code, might help solve the issues.

The idea with password hashing is that you do not use it in the SQL because the hash should never be the same so any checks that do `where password=hash` etc will always fail. The validity of the hash is tested using `password_verify` and if the password is verified then assume the user is legitimate and fetch the `type` attribute for the user before redirecting to the correct page.

```
<?php

    session_start();
    include 'dbcon.php';
    
    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset(
        $_POST['username'],
        $_POST['password']
    )){
    
        if( !isset( $_SESSION['count'] ) )$_SESSION['count']=0;
        
        $usernane = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT `password`,`type` FROM `users` WHERE `username`=:username LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->execute( array(':username'   =>  $usernane ) );
        $rs = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
        $hash = $rs->password;
        $type = $rs->type;
        
        if( password_verify( $password, $hash ) ){
            $_SESSION['username']=$username;
            $_SESSION['type']=$type;
            $_SESSION['page']=$type===1 ? 'AdminPage.php' : 'UserPage.php';
            
            exit( header( sprintf('Location: %s', $_SESSION['page'] ) ) );
        }else{
            $_SESSION['count']++;
            exit( header( 'Location: login.php?err=true&count='.$_SESSION['count'] ) );
        }
    }
?> 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/login.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form class="form" method="post">
            <div class="form-field">
                <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">
                <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="new-password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-field">  
                <input type="submit" value="login">
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```